# Canadian Tax Free

Tags: commerce

I am trying to add Gift Cards to a Canadian site, and those cards are to be the only tax free item on the site - We're online so the customer could be in any province.

No matter what I try, I cannot make the product tax-free.  I have created a new product type, and a new variation type, created a new product of that product type, with a variation of that variation type, and when I add it to the cart, Commerce adds sales tax even when the sales tax rate is explicitly set to None.

How can I prevent sales tax from being added to gift cards?

Comment: To answer my own question - I had to allow multiple tax rates, and set them to No Tax for all ten jurisdictions.